# In what cases can the verb "be" be omitted?

Tags: grammar

I have seen some short sentences without "be" verb.

For example:

- Enemy detected
- Loading completed

Is it grammatically correct?
Shouldn't it be:

- Enemy **is** detected
- Loading **is** completed

Comment: One such situation is in newspaper headlines like *Man stabbed to death by friend*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a rule for headline writing (and similarly brief messages such as for signs and status messages on devices) to leave out the "be" verbs. "Dangerous curve ahead" is not a complete sentence, of course, but it is an effective, and considerably shorter, notification than "There is a dangerous curve on the road ahead."